# mashape python unirest library

Tags: python, unirest

I'm trying to use unirest library to run API to dmoz. 
this is my code:

=========================================================================

```
import unirest

response = unirest.get("https://enclout-dmoz.p.mashape.com/show.json?auth_token=something&url=www.nike.com",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "another_code"
      }
    )
html= response.body()
print html
```

but I get an error message: Typeerror the object 'dict' is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the dict without brackets

```
 html = response.body
 print html
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Thanks!

Comment: Try without brackets. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes response is a dictionary. It has following members

code, headers, body and raw_body, you can get information as below

```
# print response
print "code:"+ str(response.code)
print "******************"
print "headers:"+ str(response.headers)
print "******************"
print "body:"+ str(response.body)
print "******************"
print "raw_body:"+ str(response.raw_body)
```

Check out the post http://stackandqueue.com/?p=57 which explains in detail how to make calls using unirest